# Unable to enable MailtoSender in WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to send an email from the message mediation layer in API manager and I created a sequence which calls mailto URI.

I tried to edit the deployment.toml with the following configurations, still, the mailto sender is not getting.

I have added this configuration in deployment.toml but axis2.xml is not reflecting with this after restart. Mailto sender is not getting enabled.

```
[[transport.mail.sender]]
name = "mailto"
parameter.hostname = "localhost"
parameter.port = "25"
parameter.enable_tls = true
parameter.auth = true
parameter.username = "incoming"
parameter.password = "incoming123"
parameter.from = "incoming@rsyswso2test.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail sender related axis2 configurations are not templated by default in APIM's axis2.xml. You need to template required configurations in `wso2am-3.1.0/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.j2`.

Required templates can be taken from micro-integrator `axis2.xml.j2`[L272](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/863d0caf0ec0ee2d58359fb60ebf2bd24962123b/distribution/src/resources/config-tool/templates/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.j2#L272-L278) and [L546](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/863d0caf0ec0ee2d58359fb60ebf2bd24962123b/distribution/src/resources/config-tool/templates/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.j2#L546-L552) where these configurations are already templated. Copy highlighted template values and paste in axis2.xml.j2 file in above path. Then APIM should pickup the configured values from the `deployment.toml`